# How do I use loop in Firebase function?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to run loop in Firebase function
sample data set:

[image]

I want to loop through it and print
console.log hello

Output should be like:

[image]

Comment: Please edit the following missing information into your question: What language? What platform? Admin SDK or Client SDK? What have you tried so far? What part of the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database) and [reference material](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference) has confused you?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information samthecodingman asked for, and please also responded with @.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this;

```js
sampleDataSet.forEach((d)=>{
  console.log("Hello "  + d.firstName + " " + d.lastName);
})
```

if sampleDataSet is an object then we can loop object as well;

```
for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(sampleDataSet)) {
  console.log("Hello "  + value.firstName + " " + value.lastName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
database.ref("collection").once("value").then((snapshot) => {
    snapshot.forEach((userSnap) => {
        console.log('hello ' + userSnap.child(`firstName`).val() + ' ' + userSnap.child(`lastName`).val() );
        });
  });
```